# How to make an replacement for qnx sin command?

Tags: linux, qnx

I am currently working on a project which involves porting a huge application from QNX SRR to Standard Linux using POSIX commands

Currently I am stuck on the sin command that QNX implements.

Can someone guide me as to how an alternate for qnx sin be created in Linux

The application code uses sin in a lot of places to find process ids, kill processes, restart processes etc. So intention is to create a replacement for sin without really making too many changes in the application code

Answer (score 1):

The best way to proceed is to analyze exactly what sin options you use.  Making a fully functioning sin replacement is a lot of work -- it can be done, but it may turn out that you only need a small percentage of the commands.

The simplest way to proceed is to create a front-end for sin that correctly interprets the options that are actually used in your system.

Then, based on those options, issue the equivalent linux commands via the system() call.